# How to change style on change with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

I first initialize a variable with 0px:

```
<span ng-init="topStyle='0px';">
```

Then I have a block where I need that style:

```
<span ng-style="{top: '{{topStyle}}'}">
```

But when I change that value to something different, the style does not change at all. Below is what my browser shows:

```
<span ng-style="{top: '-50px'}" style="top: 0px;"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't work properly because when an update comes, the directives is not able to understand that the value has changed and so, it doesn't update the stlye attribute.

The reason is that the `ngStyle` directive just take variables within it, such as:

```
ng-style="topStyle"
```

With topStyle as:

```
{top:'0px'}
```

And then update the whole thing every time.

This is an example (clicking on click me, updates the ngStyle): http://jsfiddle.net/tdegtLb4/2/

Or, you can change `ng-style` to `style` and so the when the variable changes, the value is obviously updated accordingly.

This is the same example as the one above with `style`:

http://jsfiddle.net/tdegtLb4/1/

Comment: Awesome, i throw ng-style away and it works, like in your second jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<span ng-style="{top: topStyle}">.
```

Comment: Resault: <span ng-style="{top: topStyle}">.
Nothing added at style at all.